# Escape PS parameters when invoking from C#

Tags: c#, regex, powershell

I'm invoking a PS function from C# using this code:

```
var proc = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = PowerShellExe,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
                    Arguments = string.Concat(string.Format(@" -File ""{0}"" ", fullPathToFile), commandLineArguments)
                },
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            };
```

In the function I'm doing some regex, by replacing some settings of a config file. The result would look like:

```
<rabbitMQ messageBusURI="rabbitmq://localhost/" messageBusUserName="guest" messageBusPassword="guest" purgeOnStartup="true" timeout="00:00:30" />
```

The only problem is that I cannot escape the double quotes, therefore ending with

```
<rabbitMQ messageBusURI=rabbitmq://localhost messageBusUserName=guest messageBusPassword=guest purgeOnStartup=false timeout=00:00:30 />
```

The PS performing the Regex is

```
param(
    [string]$FilePath = $Args[0],
    [string]$RegEx = $Args[1],
    [string]$ReplacementValue = $Args[2]
)

cls

(get-content $FilePath) | foreach-object {$_ -replace $RegEx,$ReplacementValue} | set-content $FilePath
```

The value of commandLineArguments used to invoke it is:

```
" -FilePath \"MyService.exe.config\"  -RegEx \"<rabbitMQ messageBusURI=[^\\>]*>\"  -ReplacementValue \"<rabbitMQ messageBusURI=\"rabbitmq://localhost\" messageBusUserName=\"guest\" messageBusPassword=\"guest\" purgeOnStartup=\"false\" timeout=\"00:00:30\" />\" "
```

How can I escape the double quotes in commandLineArguments in order to have them in the final config file?

Comment: I looks like you have xml data.  It is not recommended to use Regex to parse xml data.  There are lots of other methods to properly parse xml.

Comment: You can use baktik (`) to escape that .

Comment: @PetSerAl not quite, the values are already escaped

Comment: @jdweng not really the point here

Comment: @RanadipDutta I tried with adding it in a string followed by two "" but it did not work. How would you insert it into a C# string?

Comment: Could you please share the step how you are adding it ?

Comment: @MaPi *values are already escaped* Your post show only C# escapement, but no escapement for `PowerShell.exe`.  `commandLineArguments = " -FilePath \"MyService.exe.config\"  -RegEx \"<rabbitMQ messageBusURI=[^\\>]*>\"  -ReplacementValue \"<rabbitMQ messageBusURI=\\\"rabbitmq://localhost\\\" messageBusUserName=\\\"guest\\\" messageBusPassword=\\\"guest\\\" purgeOnStartup=\\\"false\\\" timeout=\\\"00:00:30\\\" />\" "`

Comment: @PetSerAl nice, it worked. Make it an answer and I'll accept it